# Resolve PhpStorm magic method and property warning using PHPDoc @property and @method for $this->stdout->styles

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, phpstorm, phpdoc

I'm trying to resolve

> "Field 'stdout' not found in ..."

and

> "Method ... not found in array"

warning using PHPDocumentor notations `@property` and `@method` on PhpStorm

[image]

I was able to resolve the warning for stdout using:

```
* @property array stdout
```

[image]

But now how do you resolve the `Method 'styles' not found in array` warning? (See screenshot above)

---

I made up this code to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
* @method array $stdout->styles(array $name, array $items)
```

---

This is a CakePhp 2 project using CakePhp's Command Shell.

`stdout->styles` is declared in the framework.

For more context this is what my code looks like:

```
<?
class InvoiceShell extends AppShell {
    public $uses = array('Invoice', 'Request');

    public function main() {

        $this->stdout->styles('success', ['text' => 'green']);
        $this->stdout->styles('danger', ['text' => 'red']);
        $this->stdout->styles('bold', ['bold' => true]);

        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) What is `stdout`? 2) How it's declared? 3) if it's used like `stdout->styles` .. then why are you trying to declare `stdout` as array (when it's clearly an object here)? 3) `* @method array $stdout->styles(array $name, array $items)` -- completely wrong -- you cannot declare sub-property/sub-method this way -- only direct elements. This means (using your example) `* @method array styles(array $name, array $items)` at best (which is still wrong for your case -- but this is just to illustrate the right syntax).

Comment: Have a look at correct syntax: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md

Comment: @lazyone Thanks for replying, I've added more information to the question. `stdout` and `styles` are defined in the CakePHP framework. It is outside of my control.

Comment: So .. what `stdout` is? What type is it? Because you can easily use `* @property MyStdoutClass $stdout` and that's it (just use correct class name instead of MyStdoutClass). Unfortunately I'm not CakePHP user so cannot give you 100% correct solution straight away without knowing details. P.S. If you do not know what type `stdout` is -- you may try debugging such script -- xdebug will tell what type/class it is.

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne! I found the type, it's `ConsoleOutput`. `@property ConsoleOutput stdout` worked. If you'd like you can you create an answer out of this and I'll be more than happy to accept as as answer.

Comment: I am lazy and not above stealing someone else's comment as my own answer! :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell PHPDoc/PhpStorm the correct type for `stdout` by replacing `array` with `ConsoleOutput` in your `@property` declaration.

```
/**
 * My cool class is cool.
 *
 * @property ConsoleOutput $stdout
 */
```

In cases where the object is a generic container with its own magic accessors, you can declare an interface solely for code completion by PhpStorm. Simply declare it in a file located in one of the Sources folders for your project.

```
/**
 * @method mixed styles(string, mixed)
 * @method ...
 */
interface FakeForCodeCompletion { }
```

Then reference `FakeForCodeCompletion` (preferably a descriptive name) in your class using `@property` as if it were a real class/interface.

Answer (score 0):

Those with a similar problem can use this.

```php
/** @var $items \Data\Items | mixed */

$items = new \Data\Items;

$items->method('data');
$items->item->method('data');
```